# Pico CMS custom header

Tags: php, header, picocms

Im trying to include dynamc custom header in PicoCMS.

Simple "include 'header.php';" wont work since the theme have only index.html file and and I cant include PHP in it. My guess is I would have to make a custom plugin for this to work but Im not shure how to do it.

They have some documentation about it http://picocms.org/docs.html#plugins but i dont understand it well enough to solve my problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to solve it with creating a plugin line this:

```
class Header {

public function before_render() {
ob_start(); include 'header.php';$string = ob_get_clean();print($string);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, that you can include other parts with [Twigs include function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/functions/include.html) like so

```
{{ include('header.twig') }}
```

`header.twig` would be in your themes folder among the other template files.

Now this is static, of course. However Twig comes with a lot of functionality to include some logic into the templates. Check [the docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/)